# Merge pandas dataframes, combine same column that are not key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I would like to merge three dataframes. I have tried to simplify the problem to explain: I have `df` with columns `['1', '2', '3']` and `df1` with columns `['1', '2', '3']` and `df2` with columns `['1', '2', '3']`.

I want to merge the dataframes on keys 1 & 2.

I have tried the following (simplified):

```
new = pd.merge(df, df1, how = 'left', on = [ '1', '2'])
new1 = pd.merge(new, df2, how = 'left', on = ['1', '2'])
```

Now you get as outcome

- `new` with columns `['1', '2', '3_x', '3_y']`
- `new1` with columns `['1', '2', '3_x', '3_y', '3_z']`

while i would like

- `new` with columns `['1', '2', '3']`
- `new1` with columns `['1', '2', '3']`

Any help is welcome! I don't want to use a loop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Merge will 'merge' only the columns (and only on the columns) that you are specifying in the 'on'. That is, this is working as expected.

If you have matching columns 1 and 2 but different columns 3 and you make the merge, what should be in each column in our new output? 1 and 2 will be whatever they were in both of the originals, but there are two different options for column 3. The function of merge is to split those by different columns.

What you may want here instead is `append`. Append will put one dataframe below another, as explained on this page here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#concatenating-using-append.

This will give you an output that has the columns `'1', '2', '3'`.

```py
new = df.append(df1)
new1 = new.append(df2)
```

You may even be able to do `new = df.append([df1,df2])`, but I didn't try it and don't have 3 dataframes handy.

You did say you want to just merge on columns 1 and 2, so I may be completely missing your point here. What would you want with the data in column 3 in such a case? You may be able to achieve that by using `append` and then removing some duplicates or otherwise cleaning up this output.